# CSE-CIC-IDS2018

Tags: dataset

Who has the CSE-CIC-IDS2018 data set, ask for a copy, can you send me an email, thank you！
My Email:luobin97@163.com

Comment: I'm sorry. StackOverflow should not be used for these type of inquiries. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

check this github repository: 
https://github.com/Abuhamad/processing_CSE-CIC-IDS

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.